# Gradle: Deprecated dynamic property. How to reconfigure?

Tags: android, gradle

I get a warning from Gradle about deprecated dynamic properties.

> Creating properties on demand (a.k.a. dynamic properties) has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 2.0. Please read http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtraPropertiesExtension.html for information on the replacement for dynamic properties.
>   Deprecated dynamic property: "srcDirs" on "source set aild", value: "[src]".
>   Deprecated dynamic property "srcDirs" created in multiple locations.

Unfortunately I'm not good at Gradle syntax so I can't understand what values should be changed to migrate to new standards after I read the article above.

The project can still be build in Eclipse, so the config is like

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"
    compileSdkVersion 19

    buildTypes {
        ...
    }

    productFlavors {    
        ...
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java {
                srcDirs = ['src']
            }
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aild.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            lib.srcDirs = ['libs']
            jniLibs.srcDirs=['libs']
        }

        full {        
            java {
                srcDirs = ['flavors/full/src']
            }
        }

        light {        
            java {
                srcDirs = ['flavors/light/src']
            }

            res {
                srcDirs 'flavors/light/res'
            }

            assets {
                srcDirs 'flavors/light/assets'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error in your script is this line of code:

```ruby
aild.srcDirs = ['src']
```

In older versions of Gradle, you were allowed to dynamically add new properties during configuration. Essentially, what that line would do is create a new field named "srcDirs" on the "aild" object and set it's value. I believe the reason they are deprecating this behavior is that it is usually a code smell that represents a bug or typo. If you do actually want to dynamically create that property, you can do this:

```ruby
aild.ext.srcDirs = ['src']
```

However, I don't think this is actually what you want. After a little Googling, I think that you probably want to try changing "aild" to "aidl", or even just deleting the line all together since I don't think you're actually using it within your project.

Comment: Thanks. I would have never noticed that sneaky typo. I always read "AIDL" until I saw "changing 'aild' to 'aidl'".

Comment: Yes, sadly some Android sample projects come with this mistake: they specify 'aild' instead of 'aidl'.